# php not writing data into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

i had write a html file which will request some information from user and send it to another php file. The php file will establish the connection to database and insert the value to database. 
My database name = testdb
table name = table1
 I had do some testing on both file by calling an alert message, the alert messages was able to display in the html file,it's seen like the request from the html file cant send to the php file,so the code for inserting data to database can't execute

 My Html form as show below

```
<form id="firstPrize" method="POST" action="firstPrize.php">

<label> Number 1</label>
<input type="text" name="num1"><br>
<label> Number 2</label>
<input type="text" name="num2"><br>
<label> Number 3</label>
<input type="text" name="num3"><br>
<label> Number 4</label>
<input type="text" name="num4"><br><br><Br>
<input type="button" value="enter" name="btnSubmit" onclick="show()">

</form>
```

firstPrize.php sample code

```
 <?php

   $host = "localhost";
   $user =  "root";
   $password = "";
   mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
   mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error());
   Session_Start();
   echo("yeah");
   if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]))
   {
      $num1 = $_POST["num1"];
      $num2 = $_POST["num2"];
      $num3 = $_POST["num3"];
      $num4 = $_POST["num4"];

      mysql_query("insert into table1(num1,num2,num3,num4) values ('num1','num2','num3','num4')");
?>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing curly bracket. I'm not sure if that's related but it could be throwing a syntax error.

Comment: you're just ASSUMING that the query is succeeding. BAD assumption. Never assume success. always assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise: `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())`. And you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) as well.

Comment: So where is it falling flat? Are the wrong values being stored in the database? Are you getting an error in your PHP log? Is "yeah" getting echoed?

Comment: you forgot to close your `IF` statement

Comment: Please check your syntax. It's most likely to suffer with SQL Injection. Use prepared statements and mysqli.

Comment: check your error log. You should switch to using mysqli if you can. You are not using the variables from your form. And your missing a closing bracket for you if statement.

Comment: Plus, `('num1','num2','num3','num4')` you're literally entering those string values rather than the variables for the POST arrays.

Comment: @Fred-ii- at least that way it's not an SQL injection vulnerability! :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin It would if one of those values has `'123` and not doing `(int)$_POST["num1"]` at the very least ;-) Given if and when they do use `'$var'` rather than their `'var'`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you missed the joke.

Comment: @BillKarwin LOL! Sorry, I got it now *hehe!* Cheers (1000 more cc's of coffee required, stat!)

Comment: N.B.: The pending edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13227872 by @GaurangJoshii is attempting to add the missing closing brace `}` and answers given have made a mention about it missing. If this edit is accepted, then most or all stand at being downvoted for it, stating that some may say: *"The closing brace is there, so why the mention?"*

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @HeartBreakKid: Your problem solved or not. If not, I gave one answer regarding your issue. Which will solve your problem. Have a look t it.

Comment: the alert message still not able to display in my php code

Answer (score 1):

.Change your query to;

```
mysql_query("insert into table1(`num1`,`num2`,`num3`,`num4`) values ('".$num1."','".$num2."','".$num3."','".$num4."')");
```

followed by the closing bracket ( } ) for your if statement.

Comment: What if one of those values happens to contain an injection such as `'123`?

Comment: You are right @Fred-ii-, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Sure I'll agree. However, if the OP doesn't know about that, then they might not be a happy camper, if and when it ever happens to them ;-)

Comment: Indeed, but one thing at the time! ;) I don't want to scare the OP!

Comment: Rather scare them now instead for them to be scared "to death" later ;-) *"Where's my database???!!"* lol

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: i tested your solution but it's seen like not working

Comment: i missed a dot, try again with the . after $num3 like above.

Answer (score 1):

First, your `if` statement is missing a closing `}`.

Second, your SQL query is not inserting the variables you've set above. You've got variables like `$num1`, but then you are inserting the value just `'num'` in your SQL insert. You have to change `'num1', 'num2'...` to `'$num1', '$num2'...`

Third, please do some research on PHP Data Objects (PDO) or MYSQLi (reference links at bottom of post). `mysql_` is **deprecated** and completely vulnerable to malicious injection.

**Edit:** In addition, please see [fred -ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii)'s comments below for some sound advice on better `INSERT` queries. It's safe practice to verify that the values are of the type you're expecting prior to running them against your database.

[fred -ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) says:

> What if one of those values happens to contain an injection such as '123?
>
> *[Use]*... (int)$_POST["num1"] and check to see firsthand if the input entered is an integer. There are a few functions that will do that.

---

Use error reporting and error checking against your query during testing and assuming that you are able to use the MySQL_ API.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Otherwise, you will need to resort to either using the MySQLi_ or PDO API.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: What if one of those values happens to contain an injection such as `'123`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Quite honestly, it didn't seem like injection was a concern. And if it were, I've included links to both PDO and MYSQLi.

Comment: It's best to inform them of that (potential error/injection), since they may not know about it ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Would you suggest splitting the string like so: `"... VALUES ('".$num1."', '".$num2."' ...`? I haven't done PHP in quite a few years.

Comment: More like `(int)$_POST["num1"]` and checking to see firsthand if the input entered is an integer. There are a few functions that will do that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, I'll rectify my answer.

Comment: I suggest you pull my entire comment and added to your answer, should my comment ever disappear.

Answer (score 1):

First, your query can produce SQL Injection. Use Mysqli Prepared Statement :

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "testdb";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]))
 {
    $num1 = $_POST["num1"];
    $num2 = $_POST["num2"];
    $num3 = $_POST["num3"];
    $num4 = $_POST["num4"];

    // prepare and bind
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (num1, num2, num3, num4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4);
}
```

This function binds the parameters to the SQL query and tells the database what the parameters are. The "ssss" argument lists the types of data that the parameters are. The s character tells mysql that the parameter is a string.

The argument may be one of four types:

```
i - integer
d - double
s - string
```

Second, your `if` statement misses a closing bracket `}`

Third, your variable `$num1` is never used. You use `num1`, `num2`, but you miss the `'$'`

Comment: Noble, yet you didn't outline what was wrong with their code to start with.

Comment: You also have only 3x `?` with 4 binds.

Comment: You mention PDO but you show code using mysqli. Okay, now you've edited to correct it.

Comment: i tested your code also not working, it's a bit similar with @Nana Partykar solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   session_start();
   // always start your session before any other code

   $host = "localhost";
   $user =  "root";
   $password = "";
   mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
   mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error());


   if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]))
   {
      $num1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["num1"]);
      $num2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["num2"]);
      $num3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["num3"]);
      $num4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["num4"]);

      // mysql isn't the safest way to put your code out, however if you do, escape it. You may be better off by using prepared statements, but thats up to you, i am just fixing this code 

      mysql_query("insert into table1(num1,num2,num3,num4) 
                   values ('$num1','$num2','$num3','$num4')");

    }
?>
```

I made a few tweaks in your code and this should do it. Note my additional comments in the code, including the propper escaping your variables, because of the injection danger. Its not my place to judge you on your code, but you would be better off by using prepared statements.

This is a very good topic on this here on stack, I suggest you read it: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: As I said in my comments and in my text, he is better off with simply using prepared statements, but since Q is not asking for that, he asks why his code aint working.

Answer (score 0):

As you clearly mentioned in your question,

> " I had do some testing on both file by calling an alert message, the
>   alert messages was able to display in the html file, **it's seen like the
>   request from the html file cant send to the php file ,so the code for inserting data to database can't execute** ~@Heart Break KID "

For That,

**1)** Change

```
<input type="button" value="enter" name="btnSubmit" onclick="show()">
```

To

```
<input type="submit" value="enter" name="btnSubmit" onclick="show()">
```

here, `type='submit'` is required to submit form data..

**2)** Closing curly brackets are not available. Close `if` condition.

```
if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]))
{
    // Your query.
}
```

Now, data will go to next page. But, read this question [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

[The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

***UPDATED CODE*** (using mysqli)

**Html form**

```
<form id="firstPrize" method="POST" action="firstPrize.php">
  <label> Number 1</label>
  <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
  <label> Number 2</label>
  <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
  <label> Number 3</label>
  <input type="text" name="num3"><br>
  <label> Number 4</label>
  <input type="text" name="num4"><br><br><Br>
  <input type="submit" value="enter" name="btnSubmit" onclick="show()">
</form>
```

**firstPrize.php**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user =  "root";
$password = "";
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, "testdb");
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]))
{
  $num1 = $_POST["num1"];
  $num2 = $_POST["num2"];
  $num3 = $_POST["num3"];
  $num4 = $_POST["num4"];

  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO table1(num1,num2,num3,num4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4);

  $query123 = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
?>
```

Comment: hi,i tested your solution but the alert message in my php code still not able to display

Comment: Data is saving or not @HeartBreakKID? Because, previously It was not saving.

Comment: yes,data still not saving, I try to move to window environment and test it out, because the current testing environment is Ubuntu, not sure is it the installation problem of LAMP